# Angular Universal Error when serve:ssr, Cannot find module node

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering

I'm new to Angular Universal, and I'm not sure why it could not find node.
It is Angular 15 and Angular Universal 15.

Error

```
$ node --max-http-header-size=16384 node dist/server/main.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'frontend\node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

app.server.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UniversalInterceptor } from './universal-interceptor';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CookieModule } from 'ngx-cookie';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    CookieModule.withOptions(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: UniversalInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppServerModule { }
```

main.server.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
export { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
export { renderModule } from '@angular/platform-server'
```

tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have first run build:ssr, then serve:ssr.
The error happened both inside and outside of Docker container.

Comment: Have you done a ctrl+F for `frontend\node` in your project?